# jquery div contents real width

Tags: jquery

i have a div tag

```
<div id="openfrag">
 <script language="JavaScript" src="http://ad.uk.doubleclick.net/adj/BA_HOME/HP_Public_MSB; dcopt=ist;sz=728x90,468x60;tile=1;lan=en;ord=1265795605?" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

above script tag is third party url that may returns either image or flash object or any other of any size..
how to determine dynamic  width and height occupied by div tag using jquery ?

i tried $("#openxfrag").width()   ,but it always return the same  width that is defined in css

Comment: main requirement is, if script return contents width and height is greater than 300 ,then we need to display anchor link above the contents

Answer (score 3):

Check the width *after* the content has been loaded into it. You can check the width, or the outerWidth:

```
$("#openfrag").width();
$("#openfrag").outerWidth();
```

`outerWidth` includes padding and borders.

If you're setting a default width with CSS, you may consider removing that (as it overrides the natural width) or replacing it with `min-width` instead (assuming the future width will be larger).

Answer (score 3):

> i tried $("#openxfrag").width() ,but it always return the same width that is defined in css

Why *wouldn't* it? If you're assigning it a width in the CSS, then *that's the width it'll have*! If you want its width to be dictated by its contents, you'll have to avoid specifying a width... and you'll have to [make it shrink-wrap the contents](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap).

Only then can you expect `$("#openfrag").width()` to do something useful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to create a new, hidden div and then check its width.  It will be the size of its contents because it has no CSS defined and will expand to fit its content.

HTML:

```
<div id="getWidth" style="display: none;">
   <!-- Put contents here -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   console.log($("#getWidth").width());
</script>
```